# Does c++ compiler always insert exception-processing train into function code?

Tags: c++, performance, exception

I'm trying to dig into c++ code performance issues, and I knew that c++ compiler will(at least sometimes) generate code to deal with exception handling, the code will be appended to head or end of a function body(in assembly level).

I wonder if these exception handling code(if my code is not throwing out any exception) will bring down the c++ code performance, comparing with c code with same functionality. Or if I have any way to enable-disable such code generation in case I wish to tune performance.

e.g.

```
void func(){
   ... // I'm not using /throwing any exception here
}
```

Will compiler generate any exception-handling train for `func`? Or it depends on compiler optimization options?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a *measurable* performance problem? Are you *sure* none of the calls you make are exception-free? It's not that your particular usage will not throw exceptions, but that your calls *could* throw exceptions under other circumstances.

Comment: Look up "zero cost exceptions"

Comment: Does your function allocate memory? Then you can throw `bad_alloc`. Does it add elements to an `std::vector`? Then that could allocate memory and thus could throw `bad_alloc`. There are all kinds of subtle situations where C++ can throw if you're not *exceedingly* careful.

Comment: If you are certain a function doesn't throw and none of the functions it calls etc throws, then you can use [noexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) to specify that the function does not throw. Some compilers also allow you to disable C++ exceptions entirely (but then it's not really C++ any more, but a language variant).